# Problem With Wireshark

Tags: networking

I just recently downloaded Wireshark to test it out and get to know how capturing packets works and all of that. But I'm having this problem that the button that says ("Start capturing packets") does not work and its just gray and I'm not able to use it. The version of Wireshark that I am using is version 2.0.2.

[image: Click here to see a screenshot of the capture packets button.]

Comment: You need to be root to capture packets at the NIC. So you need to start Wireshark as root.

Comment: @Jos which you can do by typing `gksu wireshark` in the Terminal.

Comment: You can also add yourself to the wireshark group. In that case you can capture without the need to have root privileges. Take a look here http://anonscm.debian.org/viewvc/collab-maint/ext-maint/wireshark/trunk/debian/README.Debian?view=markup and here https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/7976/wireshark-setup-linux-for-nonroot-user

Comment: Running as root might not be a good idea. I get an error message "Lua: Error during loading: ... dofile has been disabled due to running Wireshark as superuser ..." if I run it as root.

Answer (score 0):

Add yourself to wireshark group and you will be able to capture packets:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common 
sudo usermod -a -G wireshark $USER
newgrp wireshark
```